# Winforms How Can I Enable Multiline Arrow on my Custom Fields

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey I Want to Get MultiLine String in my Custom Field at Winform Designer. Default Text string Can input mutiline Text. but Custom Fields Can't.

So, i Tried Define Same Category and DispId and Localizable. but it still can't input multiline text. here's my Custom field Definition Code.

```
private string _trueText;
[Description("ControlTextDescr"), Category("Appearance")]
public string TrueText
{
    get { return _trueText; }
    set
    {
        _trueText = value;
        if (_checked) txt_Shown.Text = _trueText;
        CheckAutoResize();
    }
}

private string _falseText;
[Description("ControlTextDescr"), Category("Appearance")]
[Localizable(true)]
[Bindable(true)]
[DispId(-517)]
public string FalseText
{
    get { return _falseText; }
    set
    {    
        _falseText = value.Replace("\\n",Environment.NewLine);
        if (!_checked) txt_Shown.Text = _falseText;
        CheckAutoResize();
    }
}
```

[Custom Field Image](https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAyMTNfMTM5/MDAxNTUwMDIyOTI3NTU1.6h3NTQMZUw5fsPiVObzAj2njErmUDw0FQSa6-2I12Ukg.bDHtcyeC46MYaufBZAF9mL1GrBqKKhLGkRUgqZm_XzEg.PNG.wmf1235/image.png?type=w773)

[Default Text Field Image](https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAyMTNfMjM2/MDAxNTUwMDIyOTQ4MDQy.pzbLxXozuLUIMGKNb47lHGAFDi_34FCRcFpRY7GHV2og.V4TTOmEkmKB2IPkyWxMwXDSVg9lzp9rxPFyYw9LLs8Qg.PNG.wmf1235/image.png?type=w773)

Comment: Thank you for your interest in me. The current problem has been solved by the answers given by yv989c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System.ComponentModel.EditorAttribute` attribute to achieve this behavior:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

[EditorAttribute(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public string FalseText
{
...
}

[EditorAttribute(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public string TrueText
{
...
}
```

Be sure to add `System.Design` and `System.Drawing` as references to your project.